# How to isolate data (serialization) of derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, derived-class

I start with following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
private:
    char a[4];
public:
    Base(void){memcpy(a, "Base", 4);}
    ~Base(void){}
};

class Derived :
    public Base
{
private:
    char b[8];
public:
    Derived(void){ memcpy(b, "Derived", 8);}
    ~Derived(void){}
};
```

To extract the data of the base class I would do the following:

```
int main(void)
{
    Derived derived;

    char* onlyBase = new char[sizeof(Base) + 1];//+1 for '\0'
    memcpy(onlyBase, &static_cast<Base>(derived), sizeof(Base));
    onlyBase[sizeof(Base)] = '\0';

    std::cout << onlyBase;
}
```

How can I obtain the data of only the derived part of the class?

Comment: Why are you writing something so super cumbersome and pointless? Surely `sizeof(static_cast<Base>(derived)) + 1` is just `sizeof(Base) + 1`? And instead of `memcpy` you could just write `: a { 'b', 'a', 's', 'e' }`. And you don't need `(void)`, just `()` will do.

Comment: Well,yeah. I will edit that. The `(void)` was created by my IDE and the `memcpy` is easier to edit because I don't need to split up the string into single chars.

Comment: Or make a and b actual null-terminated strings? At the moment they are not even 'C' strings. Please tell us this is just some bizarre experiment.

Comment: Generally, you have no way to know how the storage for `b` and the storage for `Base` are packed inside an instance of `Derived`. The standard doesn't specify that. If `Dervied` had two or more members, the storage for `Base` could, theoretically, be placed between them (it's unlikely in practice). So the notion of "the data of only the derived part of the class" is largely meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

It is **hacky**, it may work in your case:

```
char* onlyDerived = new char[sizeof(Derived) - sizeof(Base) + 1];//+1 for '\0'
memcpy(onlyDerived, &reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&derived) + sizeof(Base), sizeof(Derived) - sizeof(Base));
onlyDerived[sizeof(Derived) - sizeof(Base)] = '\0';
```

I discourage you to do stuff like that, you may have several problem (not portable..., alignment, padding, endianness...).

You may do something like : `char* Base::serialize() const;` instead.